kubuntu mounting partitions not in fstab
Kubuntu is mounting some partitions in media/myhomedirname/ which are not in fstab. Ive used gparted to unmount them but on restarting , they have all reappeared. How can I prevent this from happening and what is doing this ?

Please edit your question and add information about which version of Kubuntu you use. Look under System Settings>Removable Storage.

An explicit entry in /etc/fstab for that partition with the "noauto" on the line will keep it from being mounted. A side benefit is that you may choose another location than /media/yourusername for the mount to occur. e.g:
UUID=b06789d6-1234-4bb0-aa5f-c5432dac1er7 /mnt/mydirforxx        ext4    noauto,nofail,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       3

Ensure you create the dir in /mnt before using it for a mount point:
sudo mkdir /mnt/mydirforxx

With the information present, you can use a command like:
sudo mount /mnt/mydirforxx


I'm using Kubuntu 22.04

in System Settings Removable storage Ive found a number of HD partitions listed , and that seems to be causing the problem  .. But they arnt removable !!! So why is this happening?   Thanks @ubfan1 for your reply ..I'll try it tomorrow.

Having a fstab-line with noauto will not prevent mounting a partition using other methods like entries in the system settings.
